# GCC undefined reference to `addition'

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to link an external library but not linking. Using gcc version:

```
gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0
Windows 10
```

Command I'm tried:

```
gcc -g test.c -Wall -I ../inc/ -L ../lib -l:libFp.a -o test.exe
gcc -g test.c -Wall -I ../inc/ -L ../lib64 -l:libFp.a -o test.exe
gcc -g -Wall -I ../inc/ -L ../lib -l:libFp.a test.c -o test.exe
gcc -g -Wall ../lib/libFp.a  test.c -I ../inc/ -o test.exe
```

Error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\cciWnORn.o: in function `main':
D:\C_Training\utils\XXXXXXXX\testApp/test.c:35: undefined reference to `addition'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Folder Hierarchy:

```
XXXX
  ==docs
  ==inc
  ==lib
    --libFp.a
    --fP.lib
  ==lib64
    --libFp.a
  ==src
  ==testApp [cwd]
    --test.c
```

Tried different solutions from StackOverflow but still same error.

Update: `gcc -g -Wall -I ../inc -L ../lib test.c -o test.exe -lFp -Xlinker --verbose` command output

[Linker Output Verbose](https://pastebin.pl/view/5ed8cbc0)

Comment: Did *all* of those fail with the *same* error? I'd be shocked if they did. Also, is `test.c` really if the `XXXX` folder, or is it in `src`. Obviously it matters, depending on the cwd directory path at the time of invoke paths to sources, includes, and libs, will obviously differ.

Comment: Yes. test.c is in XXXX folder... I tried different folder also. And Yes same error

Comment: The same code works in Visual Studio but library changed to fP.lib

Comment: Tried with absolute path also